# Call class via function

Tags: d

i was playing around with d, its possible to make the code bellow work without using the for example auto test1 = new Word("hello"); ??

```
import std.stdio;
import std.conv : to;
import std.digest.sha;
import std.algorithm;





class Word {
    string thisWord;

    this(string fWord) {
        thisWord = fWord;   
    }

    string toHex(){
        return (cast(ubyte[]) thisWord).toHexString;
    }
}


string test(const Word& thisword){
    writeln(thisword.toHex)
}



void main() {

    test("hello");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: if my code cann works, without auto test1 = new Word("hello");
 writeln(test1.toHex);

Comment: just make it an ordinary function without wrapping it in a class.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're asking for implicit conversion as in [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). D has only a few of these - there are some default implicit conversions in the language (int to float, non-const to const), and [alias this](https://dlang.org/spec/class.html#alias-this) for converting a type you're in control of to something else.

However, there is no method for converting some type you don't control into something else (e.g. string to a class instance). As this seems to be what you want, the answer is no, D can't do that.

A few other things in your code: `string test(const Word& thisword)` is not D - D classes are always reference types, and so adding C++'s ampersand is unnecessary, and also doesn't work (references in D are marked with `ref` instead of `&`).

Also, consider why you'd want to use a class instead of a struct in this case - most D code uses a lot of structs and few classes, since the main attraction of classes in D is inheritance (and the second attraction is reference behavior).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is *no - it is not possible*. Something, somewhere needs to instantiate an object of type Word and pass it to the test(Word) function. You can for an example add an overloaded function (wrapper) `test(string)` that takes a string, and calls the original `test(Word)` function that you have in your code. Something like:

```
string test(string arg){
    test(new Word(arg);
}
```